# Does the royal broadsword by the training dummies at Lookout Landing respawn?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

I'm looking for a reliable source of royal broadswords for building powerful flurry rush weapons. Beside the training dummies in Lookout Landing are one each of Soldier's, Knight's, and Royal Broadswords. If you interact with one, the person whaling away at the practice dummy gives it to you. I've already claimed the royal broadsword and would like to know whether it respawns each blood moon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think they respawn. However, after completing the Zora questline, there is no way to get those weapons at Lookout Landing.

If you want there is one at floating Hyrule Castle -315 971 that respawns each blood moon.

A better way to get Royal Broadswords is by killing Hinoxes,
but I would recommend: (spoiler if you haven't yet explored the depths)

> Once you have broken a weapon at least once, there is a chance for it to respawn in the depths in its pristine form at **shadow soldiers**.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm they don't respawn.
I picked one up, next night a Blood moon occurred and the sword wasn't there.